# jQuery - Flip: Size of flipped div is smaller than the front div

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using this jQuery-Plugin: https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

The problem is that, when I flip a div, the flipped div is smaller than it should be. Take a look at this gif:

[image]

I want that the size of the flipped div is the same as the original div. What is going wrong?

Here is my implementation:

```
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div id="<%=i%>" value="<%=card[1]%>" class="flip p-2">

      <div class="front yellowishcard text-center cardsize p-3">
        <%= card[0] %>
      </div>

      <div class="back yellowishcard text-center cardsize p-3">
        <%= card[0] %>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see, both divs have the same classes, except for 'front' and 'back'. I checked my css-file and I didn't add any styling to front or back.

My css:

```
.yellowishcard {
    background: #F3E380;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F3E380, #E7C700);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F3E380, #E7C700);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F3E380, #E7C700);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F3E380, #E7C700);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F3E380, #E7C700);
    -webkit-border-radius: 11;
    -moz-border-radius: 11;
    border-radius: 11px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #666666;
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #666666;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #666666;
}

.cardsize {
    height: 250px !important;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

'p-2' and 'p-3' are classes from bootstrap 4:https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/

'flip' has no styling, It is only there for my javascript to work.

The same problem occurs, when I only use these classes: `back yellowishcard` and `front yellowishcard`.

Comment: `display:block;` should fix it for `.cardsize`

Comment: @Martijn I deleted "display:flex;" and added "display:block;", but the same problem remains. Any further suggestions?

Comment: try to remove `align-items` from `.cardsize` .. you already have bootstraped `text-center` class defined.. or try to remove that class from html

Comment: @KresimirPendic I removed align-items and the problem remains. The reason I need this, is to align items vertically. Text-center only centers text horizontally.

Comment: ok,, can you update your question with `flip` and `p-2,p-3` css class definitions?

Comment: @KresimirPendic I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The problem was hinted by **KresimirPendic**. The problem was caused by a p-2. When I changed p-2 to m-2, the problem disappears. Working implementation:

```
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div id="<%=i%>" value="<%=card[1]%>" class="flip m-2">

  <div class="front yellowishcard text-center cardsize p-3">
    <%= card[0] %>
  </div>

  <div class="back yellowishcard text-center cardsize p-3">
    <%= card[0] %>
  </div>

</div>
```